# How Do I Get Crontab to Run a Whole Directory of PHP Files?

Tags: php, cron

I've created a little program that will generate php files and place them into a '/crons' folder to allow cron jobs to execute the files. These php files will be generated and named dynamically based on user input. So I was wondering how I could get Crontab to execute ALL of the php scripts that are in that '/crons' directory, simultaneously. Is it some kind of regular expression (regEx) with a wildcard to run the entire directory, as shown below (something similar to it)?

**`*/1 * * * * php /var/www/mywebsite.com/path-to-my-awesome-php-scripts/crons/*`**

What exactly would I need to do? Does this require a bash or shell script? (I have no experience with bash or shell). Thanks.

Comment: Is that not working?

Comment: Oh, I havent actually tried that, but does cron accept a regEx wildcard at the end of a directory? I will give it a try. Just wondering if this is supposed to work and if not, is it something similar to this?

Comment: You can see in `/etc/crontab` it starts `SHELL=/bin/sh`.

Comment: Ok, so I've tested it and it only seems to run 1 php file instead of the 2 php files that I have in the directory. Maybe the cron is only able to select the first file.

Comment: With no experience with bash or shell, I would create another php script that will handle your logic with `path-to-my-awesome-php-scripts/crons/*` and you simply call it in cron job `*/1 * * * * php /var/[...]/path-to-my-awesome-php-scripts/cronjob.php`

Comment: Right, and I have though of that Chris such as a master file with includes in it, but I was wondering if there was already a simple way to do it with a crontab command.

Comment: If there was a problem running the other scripts, there should be errors?

Answer (score 1):

When you run `php *.php` then PHP interpreter executes only the first file. You can check it outside of `cron` environment.

You can use `run-parts` to run all executables in a specific directory. See [run-parts man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/run-parts.8.html)

You'll need to make your PHP files executable with a proper `#!` header and executable bit.
Your `crontab` should look like

```
*/1 * * * * run-parts /var/www/mywebsite.com/path-to-my-awesome-php-scripts/crons
```

Comment: Hi Alex, can you show me an example of how to make proper #! headers and an executable bit? I've never seen this before in php. If you can show me a quick example with proper syntax of what you're referring to I can get the visuals and write it properly from that point on. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @AaronEsteban, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21731745/how-to-add-shebang-with-php-script-on-linux